# AES decryption behaviour changed in Android N

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

We implemented chunked file decryption in a way that the initialization vector is added at the beginning of the file and followed by the encrypted data. The following decryption method decrypts the file and write:

```
private void decrypt_AES_CBC_PKCS7(final byte[] symKeyBytes, final FileInputStream inputStream, final FileOutputStream outputStream) throws Exception {

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    // Read init vector
    final byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    inputStream.read(iv, 0, 16);

    // Prepare for decryption
    final SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(symKeyBytes, "AES");
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding", new BouncyCastleProvider());
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

    // Decrypt chunk by chunk
    int chunkLen = 0;
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE_DECRTPY]; // CHUNK_SIZE_DECRTPY = 20 * 1024 * 1024;

    while ((chunkLen = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {

        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(buffer, 0, chunkLen);

        outputStream.write(decrypted, 0, decrypted.length);
    }

    // close streams
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

The code worked fine in earlier Android versions (L & M), but when we tried it on Nexus 5X with Android N, 16 "junk" bytes were inserted at the begginning of the resulting file. This happens only in files that consist of one chunk only, i.e., files with size larger than one chunk would be decrypted correctly and no extra bytes would be prepended. Interestingly, when the code is run with Android studio debugger attached, with a breakpoint between reading IV and reading input stream, the decryption works fine and no extra bytes appear in the output file.

Example encrypted file (IV is visible as first 16 bytes, i.e., first row):

[Example encrypted file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEyVX.png)

Example decrypted file, first 16 bytes are added only in Android N:

[Example decrypted file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IK3x.png)

All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Samples, in hex, would help answer the questions: "junk" bytes" does not help. Include the IV, clear data, encrypted data and incorrect decrypted data.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @zaph , the post has been updated with relevant screenshots.

Comment: Shouldn't you check the returned `int` value of `inputStream.read(iv, 0, 16)` to check that it actually read 16 bytes (and not less)?

Comment: Calling `doFinal` in a loop doesn't make sense, as it would unpad multiple times. That can however not be the current issue as the remaining plaintext bytes should still be correct.

Comment: Screenshots are not a god way to present the information, make it easy for those who may help..

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @martijno, I checked the result of `inputStream.read(iv, 0, 16)` and it turned out that the first invocation of it returns -1 in Android N. So, I modified the part of the code that reads the IV:

```
 final byte[] iv = new byte[16];
 int result;
 int numTries = 0;
 int MAX_NUM_TRIES = 2;

 do {
    result = inputStream.read(iv, 0, 16);
    ++numTries;
 } while (result == -1 && numTries < MAX_NUM_TRIES);

 if (result == -1) {
     throw new Exception("Failed to read IV from file!");
 }
```

It turns out that two tries for reading IV are enough, we'll test this further when more Android N devices become available.